# How to call and display a database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, html, database, phpmyadmin

My assignment is to create two tables in phpMyAdmin, and then to create a simple form where the user can click a button and have the two tables displayed. I have the landing page for the assignment finished with header and search bar and button, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to bring the two tables in from the database and display them once the button is clicked.

I have had a tutor help with some of the code but I haven't been able to get it to work properly and would love any further help.

Here is the code I have now (the two separate php code chunks are two ways people tried to help me do it but I don't know which works or how to implement it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected Successfully";
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Health Club Patron and Class Information</h1>
<form name="contact-form" action="" method="post" id="contact-form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Search">Search</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" search="your_name" placeholder="Search" required>
</div>
<button type="print" class="btn btn-primary" name="print" value="Print" id="submit_form">Print</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>



$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password

mysql_select_db('hrmwaitrose');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results

echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['age'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
```

Comment: Understanding that the problem is VERY specific from your perspective, your question is overly broad and participants are likely to think you're asking them to do your work for you. I suggest that you go back and pick up the fundamental areas of php that are pertinent to your question and then -- if necessary -- come back and update the question with the part(s) you're still having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at examples on this website, good example's taken from W3 schools to learn with some simple examples. 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

And a form handling example in PHP https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

You setup a php file such as post.php then your form will post to that endpoint. Or if you are posting a PHP form to itself you use `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>` for the post address in the form. When learning, try taking these simpler like the example's below than building from that, so you get the basic idea.

Here's a few examples, this one just grabs the rows from the database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; // Server host
$username = "username"; // Database username
$password = "password"; // Database password
$dbname = "hrmwaitrose"; // Your database name

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// Select the rows name and age from employee
$sql = "SELECT name, age FROM employee";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["age"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Simple example post a form to PHP file a different URL, not posting to itself.
Filename: **index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="results.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then your results.php contains
Filename: **results.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an example using a form posting to itself, instead of the example's above which post to another file. Using `$_GET["name"]` you are grabbing the post variable's from the URL and then you can query your database, unless you are using `_POST`. If your posting directly to the same file you would do something like this, which I think your question is asking.

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)): ?>
    Welcome, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>!<br>
    Your age is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["age"]); ?>.<br>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```